# BFTask (used in AWS iOS SDK) returns task.error = nil when there is an error

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using the AWS iOS SDK Cognito service for authentication. My simulator does not have a network connection. When I run my app, I'd like to handle the error but the problem is that AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider does not return an error to me. I see the following message in my log, so I know there is an error:

GetId failed. Error is [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)"

I know I could code in a workaround to check my internet connection before starting, but I have also seen this same problem with other areas of the SDK, for example when I try to delete a row in DynamoDB with the wrong AWSDynamoDBModel. I see an error in my log, but task.error is returned as nil.

Is there another area that I should be checking for errors?

I'm using Xcode 6, and AWS iOS SDK 2.0.12. The only way to reproduce the issue would be to add AWS cognate to your project, and then run the app while you have no network connection. Here is the snippet where I should be seeing the error, but it's not returning one (look for task.error): 
    `-(void)completeLogin:(NSDictionary *)logins {
        BFTask *task;
        if (self.provider == nil) {
            task = [self initializeClients:logins];
        }
        else {
            NSMutableDictionary *merge = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:self.provider.logins];
            [merge addEntriesFromDictionary:logins];
            self.provider.logins = merge;
            // Force a refresh of credentials to see if we need to merge
            task = [self.provider refresh];
        }
        [task continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
            if (self.callback != nil) {
                self.callback(task.error); //This is always nil
                NSLog(@"callback set to nil in in completeLogin");
                self.callback = nil;
            }
            return nil;
        }];
    }`

Comment: Can you share a code snippet to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Can you also indicate which version of the SDK you are using?

Comment: There have been a number of updates to the SDK that include fixes for some error handling in the CognitoCredentialsProvider. Can you please try with the latest SDK (2.0.12 as of 11/25/2014) and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: I just upgraded to 2.0.12 and am having the same problem. I am also using Facebook, which also has Bolts (BFTask), could it be that?